# Build fails with com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0 because of StackOverflowError

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services

I just switched from

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

As result in Android Studio my build fails with following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.isEmpty(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:246)
at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDomainObjectSet$DomainObjectCompositeCollection.isEmpty(CompositeDomainObjectSet.java:172)
at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDomainObjectSet.iterator(CompositeDomainObjectSet.java:111)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DelegatingDomainObjectSet.iterator(DelegatingDomainObjectSet.java:106)
at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDomainObjectSet$DomainObjectCompositeCollection.iterator(CompositeDomainObjectSet.java:201)
at org.gradle.api.internal.SetIterator.of(SetIterator.java:34)
at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDomainObjectSet.iterator(CompositeDomainObjectSet.java:114)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DelegatingDomainObjectSet.iterator(DelegatingDomainObjectSet.java:106)
at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDomainObjectSet$DomainObjectCompositeCollection.iterator(CompositeDomainObjectSet.java:201)
at org.gradle.api.internal.SetIterator.of(SetIterator.java:34)
at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDomainObjectSet.iterator(CompositeDomainObjectSet.java:114)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DelegatingDomainObjectSet.iterator(DelegatingDomainObjectSet.java:106)
at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDomainObjectSet$DomainObjectCompositeCollection.iterator(CompositeDomainObjectSet.java:201)
at org.gradle.api.internal.SetIterator.of(SetIterator.java:34)
at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDomainObjectSet.iterator(CompositeDomainObjectSet.java:114)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DelegatingDomainObjectSet.iterator(DelegatingDomainObjectSet.java:106)
at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDomainObjectSet$DomainObjectCompositeCollection.iterator(CompositeDomainObjectSet.java:201)
at org.gradle.api.internal.SetIterator.of(SetIterator.java:34)
at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDomainObjectSet.iterator(CompositeDomainObjectSet.java:114)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DelegatingDomainObjectSet.iterator(DelegatingDomainObjectSet.java:106)
at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.getAllDependencies(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy:267)
at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.getAllDependencies(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy:274)
at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.getAllDependencies(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy:274)
at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.getAllDependencies(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy:274)
```

The build is also successful when I build from command line or when I remove from build file

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

As side note: I am also using google maps and firebase products of version 12.0.0 like crashlytics and analytics. Additionally the project is structured with a base-feature and multiple sub-features as described in https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/structure.html

Any idea what might be wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has been fixed in version `3.2.1` of the Google Play Services plugin.

Comment: Do you by any chance can point us to a changelog for the plugin? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Unfortunately not :( I just coincidentally noticed that this bug has been fixed with this version of the plugin.

Comment: In your Project's root build.gradle: buildscript { dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2' } }